# FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1), this is my error occur while decoding my json format

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I am trying to post and fetch data using http package. I have a function inside onPressedEvent

```
onPressed: () {
     getAttendance();
},
```

This is the function triggering the getAttendanceStatus() method.

```
void getAttendance() async {
    List returnedData = await getAttendanceStatus(context);
    print(returnedData);
  }
```

The problem is with the getAttendanceStatus() method......

```
Future<List> getAttendanceStatus(BuildContext context) async {
  List decodedData;

  final _url = 'https://abcd.000webhostapp.com/abcd.php';

  try {
    final response = await http.post(_url, body: {
      'dept': 'Computer',
      'year': '4',
      'sem': 'even',
      'sec': 'A',
      'day': 'monday',
      'roll_number': '1807025',
    });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      var data = response.body;
      decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
      print('decodedData: $decodedData');
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Catch: $e');
  }
  return decodedData;
}
```

This is the actual data,that I am fetching from the internet. Which is nothing but response.body

```
[{"monday":"EBS","course_code":"UCEC039","1807025":"0","date":"Jan 26"},{"monday":"ITP II","course_code":"UCEC047","1807025":"0","date":"Jan 26"}]
```

This is the error:

```
I/flutter (24940): Catch:: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (24940): Array
I/flutter (24940): ^
I/flutter (24940): null
```

Comment: I don't see anything related to php.

Comment: I have updated, but I think the question is very related to Dart.

Comment: You may want to check the datat you get before feeding it into the json decoder...

Comment: @JulianReschke how to resolve this?

Comment: how about printing the value and to see what's in?

Answer (score 0):

It's the semicolon at the end of the response that's causing the problem.

I've tested the response using [this tool](https://freeonlinetools24.com/json-decode), and found that removing the semicolon at the end makes results in a valid JSON string.

Comment: Yeah, I have made mistake while typing the question. But thats not my problem :) and thankyou I have updated my issue.

Comment: Actually, the problem arise when i Add this code         decodedData = jsonDecode(data);

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to pass a string, not an array, to the body field. So just jsonEncode your body like this:

```
  try {
    final response = await http.post(_url, body: 
      jsonEncode({
      'dept': 'Computer',
      'year': '4',
      'sem': 'even',
      'sec': 'A',
      'day': 'monday',
      'roll_number': '1807025',
    },
  ),
);
```

Also, you may want to add a timeout to your request, and as mentioned above you'll want to surround your jsonDecode with a try/catch as well in case the response is not valid json.

Comment: My response is an Array. I was able to fetch data, but I am unable to Decode it. This is the problem scenario.

Comment: @arud please show the full error log in your post, then we can help you better.

Comment: Put a print statement `print(response.body.runtimeType)` to check what type you're inputting to jsonDecode. If it is an array, try to use the 0 index of that array.